# Gravitational collapse seen by a distant observer

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, observers, gravitational-collapse

Consider the gravitational collapse of a spherically symmetric dust cloud, as seen by a distant observer.

The Oppenheimer-Snyder solution tells us that, at some point during the collapse, the event horizon forms, and grows in time until it reaches $r=2M$, with $M$ mass of the cloud.

The distant observer cannot see anything crossing the event horizon within a finite value of their coordinate time, but still, the horizon grows during the collapse.

Does this mean that, in the distant observer frame, the growing horizon "pushes away" matter from the center of the cloud to $r=2M$? In other words, in the distant observer frame, does the horizon change the shape of the cloud from a sphere to a spherical shell that shrinks more and more in time, eventually (at $t=\infty$) coinciding with the surface $r=2M$?

The only way for this not to happen, as far as I can see now, is that the horizon would never form in the distant observer frame, which, if I am not mistaken, means that a black hole would never form.

If you happen to know any references where this is discussed, please share them!

Comment: Thanks, I have never thought about it this way! So, when the horizon has grown to, say, $r=M$, that is, it is at $1M$ seconds from the center, where is the matter that was occupying the space between $r=0$ and $r=M$ BEFORE the appearance of the horizon? Has it been "pushed" to the region "r>M"? (I keep saying "pushed" because the matter cannot cross the event horizon for the distant observer, so it stays in a region where the $r$ coordinate remains spacelike)

Comment: In the Oppenheimer-Snyder solution, the Schwarzschild metric is defined outside the dust cloud, whereas a closed FLRW metric (in comoving coordinates) is defined inside the dust cloud. The horizon starts forming inside the dust cloud, so I am not sure if we can use results from the Schwarzschild solution to describe what happens to it, when it is still inside the dust cloud.

Comment: So what happens to the star as time passes, for the distant observer? I understand that the surface of the star would tend to $r=2M$, reaching it at $t=\infty$, but what would happen to a shell of matter originally placed at $r=M$?

Comment: Thanks! So, intuitively, as I was saying in the original question, the matter in the interior of the star is pushed away from the growing horizon, and a thin shell of matter forms within $r\in (2M,2M+\epsilon)$, with $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ (by $r$ I mean the Schwarzschild coordinate, not the proper radius; so matter is "pushed away" in Schwarzschild coordinates). Am I correct?